# This is my final code i am getting an error on "if(Users[B].substring(0,1) == "1"){ //Find String Cut Char Function"

Tags: java

Having trouble finding how to solve this error, please help me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class work {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String Login;
        int A,B,C,D,NumTea,NumStu,PerClass,Teacher,Total,LoginID,LoginType,Choice;

        String[] Users = new String[20];

        Scanner FileScan;
        FileScan = new Scanner(new File("users.txt"));    
        A = 0;

        while (FileScan.hasNext())
        {
            Users[A] = FileScan.nextLine(); //Find the function to fix this
            A++;
        }

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Ready to get database of students and teachers
        // Arrays for seperating out students from teachers


        String[] Teachers = new String[1000];
        String[] Students = new String[1000];

        Total = A;

        System.out.println("Please wait for the system to intilize...");

        B=0;
        C=0;

        //Ready to seperate students from teachers in for loops

        for(B=0;B<=A;B++){
            if(Users[B].substring(0,1) == "1"){ //Find String Cut Char Function
                Students[C] = Users[B];
                C=C+1;
            }
        }

        NumStu = C+1;
        C=0;

        for(B=0;B<=A;B++){
            if(Users[B].substring(0,1) == "2"){ //Find String Cut Char Function
                Teachers[C] = Users[B];
                C=C+1;
            }
        }

        NumTea = C+1;

        System.out.println("Each teacher has 1 class a day but each student has 2 classes per day");
        System.out.println("There are " + NumTea + " teachers in the school therefore there are " + (NumTea) + " classes");
        System.out.println("There are " + NumStu + " students in the school therefore there are " + ((NumStu*2)/NumTea) + " kids per class on average"); //Diving correctly?

        PerClass = ((NumStu*2)/NumTea);

        int[][] StudentClass = new int[NumStu][2]; //Looks at what classes each student has
        int[][] TeacherClass = new int[NumTea][1000]; //Looks at what students each teacher has

        for(B=0;B<=(NumStu-1);B++){
            Teacher = (int)(Math.random()*NumTea); //Import Math Library and check random function
            StudentClass[B][0] = Teacher; //Assigning first class
            Teacher = (int)(Math.random()*NumTea);
            StudentClass[B][1] = Teacher; //Assigning second class
            if(StudentClass[B][0] == StudentClass[B][1]){  //Error checking for same class
                Teacher = (int)(Math.random()*NumTea);
                StudentClass[B][1] = Teacher;
            }
        }

        //Ready to look at student classes and assign them to teachers

        B=0;
        C=0;
        D=0;

        int[] StuClass = new int[NumTea]; //Looks at how many students are in each class

        for(B=0;B<=(NumTea-1);B++){
            D=0;
            for(C=0;C<=(NumStu-1);C++){
                if(StudentClass[C][0] == B || StudentClass[C][1] == B){
                    TeacherClass[B][D] = C;
                    D=D+1;
                }
            }
            StuClass[B] = D;
        }

        System.out.println("Classes print out:");

        // Going to print out all students and all teachers in each class

        A=0;
        B=0;

        for(A=0;A<=(NumTea-1);A++){
            System.out.println(Teachers[A] + "'s class (" + (StuClass[A]+1) + "):");
            for(B=0;B<=(StuClass[A]);B++){
                System.out.println("           " + Students[(TeacherClass[A][B])]);
            }
        }

        while(1==1){

            System.out.println("Welcome to Wayzata WHS's SGS (Scheduling and Grading System)");
            System.out.println("Login:");

            Login = reader.nextLine();

            A = 0;
            LoginType = 0;
            LoginID = 0;

            for(A=0;A<=(NumStu-1);A++){
                if(Students[A].toLowerCase() == Login.toLowerCase()){ //Check to see if string lower is correct
                    System.out.println("Found your account, linking you with the system...");
                    LoginID = A;
                    LoginType = 1;
                }
            }

            for(A=0;A<=(NumTea-1);A++){
                if(Teachers[A].toLowerCase() == Login.toLowerCase()){ //Check to see if string lower is correct
                    System.out.println("Found your account, linking you with the system...");
                    LoginID = A;
                    LoginType = 2;
                }
            }

            //The user has typed in a name and the system has recognized it and found it in the system the program has logged ethier a student or teacher in

            if(LoginType == 1){
                System.out.println("Welcome " + Students[LoginID] + "! Signed in as: STUDENT");
                System.out.println("What would you like to do today?");
                System.out.println("1: See grades");
                System.out.println("2: Logout");
                Choice = reader.nextInt();

                if(Choice == 1){
                    System.out.println("1: " + Teachers[(StudentClass[LoginID][0])] + "'s Class");
                    System.out.println("2: " + Teachers[(StudentClass[LoginID][1])] + "'s Class");
                    Choice = reader.nextInt();
                    //c.PrintClassGrades(LoginID,Choice); //Add a class for this
                }
            }else if(LoginType == 2){
                System.out.println("Welcome " + Teachers[LoginID] + "! Signed in as: TEACHER");
                System.out.println("What would you like to do today?");
                System.out.println("1: Do attendance");
                System.out.println("2: Look at class grades");
                System.out.println("3: Add grade to gradebook");
                System.out.println("4: Logout");
                Choice = reader.nextInt();

                if(Choice == 1){
                    //c.Attendance(LoginID); //Add a class for this
                }else if(Choice == 2){
                    //c.ClassGrades(LoginID); //Add a class for this
                }else if(Choice == 3){
                    //c.AddGrade(LoginID);//Add a class for this
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: don't compare Strings with `==`, use `.equals()`!

Comment: and btw what is your error message?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at work.main(work.java:39)

Answer (score 2):

(I'd post this as a comment, but I'm not sure it would fit.)

Here are some suggestions for making it easier to get your program working:

Separate out your declarations. Have one purpose for each variable, and have the identifier indicate that purpose.

During debug, use java.util.Random initialized with a fixed seed, not Math.random. With Math.random, you get a different sequence of numbers every time you run.

Look really carefully at the output. Where is the first point at which it did something you did not expect? Add more output between the last time everything was the way you expected and the first time it was not.

Work small versions of your problem with paper and pencil.

Comment: *"(I'd post this as a comment, but I'm not sure it would fit.)"*  Based on *"-27 characters left"* I'd say it is a certainty it would not. ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**, never use the `==` operator when comparing strings, **always** use `String.equals()`.:

```
if ("1".equals(Users[B].substring(0, 1))
```

**Second.** You are passing beyond the last index of the number of strings you have read in. Change (x2):

```
for (B = 0; B <= A; B++) {
```

to

```
for (B = 0; B < A; B++) {
```

All entries in your array:

```
String[] Users = new String[20];
```

will be initialized to `null` by default, leading to an `NullPointerException` when you try & access :

```
Users[B].substring(0, 1)
```

when `B = A`.

This mistake is made twice more, change to:

```
for (A = 0; A < (NumTea - 1); A++) {
```

Comment: willing to pay someone to help me with this program, email me at finlemat000@isd284.com

Comment: @user1801748 You will be all the richer for doing this yourself :)

Comment: if only i could figure out how to fix this

Comment: I've given you the answer to the 'NullPointerException` issue here.

Comment: now when i run it this appears

Comment: Each teacher has 1 class a day but each student has 2 classes per day
There are 1 teachers in the school therefore there are 1 classes
There are 1 students in the school therefore there are 2 kids per class on average
Classes print out:
null's class (2):
           null
           null
Welcome to Wayzata WHS's SGS (Scheduling and Grading System)
Login:
eric
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at work.main(work.java:112)